# Working with local language in HTML

Tags: html

I have created an html page i have put local language Kannada code:kn in it. I am able to open the same in google chrome successfully, but when trying to open in Internet explorer it doesnot displays local language but only english. What are the changes i need to make in my html. Please guide me to fix it. i have tried using code="kn" but it did not work, Below is the sample code i am trying.

```
<html lang= "kn">
 <head>
  <title>Raisededfg</title>

 </head>

 <body>
  <header>


 </header>
 <div class="divider"></div>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <p>
                    <strong>
                        ಸಿರಿಗನ್ನಡಂ ಗೆಲ್ಗೆ  ಸಿರಿಗನ್ನಡಂ ಬಾಳ್ಗೆ 
                        <br/>
                        ಸಿರಿಗನ್ನಡಂ ಗೆಲ್ಗೆ  ಸಿರಿಗನ್ನಡಂ ಬಾಳ್ಗೆ 
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <p>
                    <strong>For </strong>
                    <strong>18/10/2017</strong>
                    <strong>: </strong>
                    <strong>2</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="179">
                <p>
                    <strong>ಹುಟ್ಟು</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="70">
                <p align="center">
                    <strong>ಕನಿಷ್ಠ</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="70">
                <p align="center">
                    <strong>ಗರಿಷ್ಠ</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <strong>Cere</strong>
                </p>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: Internet Explorer version is  11.0.9600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag in document's head section:

```
<html lang="kn">
 <head>
   <title>Raisededfg</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
...
```

[image]